# Numpy array condition and apply a formula

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, conditional-statements, formula

I have a default numpy array (speed, pressure or temperature data) like this:

```
a=[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9.]
   [ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9.]
   [ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9.]
   [30. 31. 32. 33. 34. 35. 36. 37. 38. 39.]
   [40. 41. 42. 43. 44. 45. 46. 47. nan 49.]]
```

I need to apply the following conditions and then use the corresponding formula

```
a<5 (a*5)+4
a>5 (a**2.)-2
```

I tried using:

```
a[a<5]=(a[a<5]*5.)+4.
```

but it does not work and I have also used the method creating Boolean matrices and then multiplying them by the formulas corresponding to the condition, like this:

```
les=(a<5.).astype(float)
mayor=(a>5.).astype(float)

les=les*((a*5)+4)
mayor=mayor*((a**2.)-2)

b=les+mayor
```

This works but it uses many lines of code and I think it is impractical and I would like to know if there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: The number of lines of code is not a measure of practicality.  You could write as 1 line but it wouldn't be as readable.  `np.where` should also work.

Comment: `np.where(a<5, (a*5)+4, (a**2)-2)`

Comment: What about `a = 5` ? Should the value 5 be kept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a nested list comprehension

```
answer = [[(x*5)+4 if x<5 else (x**2.)-2 for x in row] for row in a]
```

This will essentially go row by row creating a new list for each row using the conditions you have defined to convert each element

Comment: I don't think this will scale as well.  It's all scalar math.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by hpaulj in comments, you could use np.where:

```
>>> np.where(a<5, (a*5)+4, (a**2)-2)

array([[4., 9., 14., 19., 24., 23., 34., 47., 62., 79.],
       [4., 9., 14., 19., 24., 23., 34., 47., 62., 79.],
       [4., 9., 14., 19., 24., 23., 34., 47., 62., 79.],
       [898., 959., 1022., 1087., 1154., 1223., 1294., 1367., 1442., 1519.],
       [1598., 1679., 1762., 1847., 1934., 2023., 2114., 2207., nan, 2399.]])
```

However, according to the conditions that you provided:

```
a<5: (a*5)+4
a>5: (a**2.)-2
```

for `a = 5` the value of 5 should be kept unchanged. Here's one way to do it:

```
b = a.copy()
b[a<5] = a[a<5]*5 + 4
b[a>5] = a[a>5]**2 - 2
```

Result:

```
array([[4., 9., 14., 19., 24., 5., 34., 47., 62., 79.],
       [4., 9., 14., 19., 24., 5., 34., 47., 62., 79.],
       [4., 9., 14., 19., 24., 5., 34., 47., 62., 79.],
       [898., 959., 1022., 1087., 1154., 1223., 1294., 1367., 1442., 1519.],
       [1598., 1679., 1762., 1847., 1934., 2023., 2114., 2207., nan, 2399.]])
```